# Getting error when trying to insert a value into a database and get the last inserted id

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-deployment

I am doing a web development in ASP.net with C#.

I am trying to insert some values into the database and get a last inserted id.

This is my code:

```
int  userno2 =  Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_id"].ToString());
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString);

createorder = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO order (user_id, date) VALUES ('" + userno2 + "', '12-12-2013');select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
order = new DataSet();
createorder.Fill(order, "or_det");

Int32 ord_id = Convert.ToInt32(order.Tables[0].Rows[0]["order_id"].ToString());
```

When I try to execute the program it gives an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Can anyone please help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

order is a reserved word in SQL. If you are using SQL Server, use square brackets to escape it []:

```
createorder = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO [order] (user_id, date) VALUES ('" + userno2 + "', '12-12-2013');select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
```

Answer (score 5):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword in T-SQL.

Either don't call your table `ORDER`, or then you need to "escape" the name with square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [order](user_id, date) VALUES ('" + userno2 + "', '12-12-2013');select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
```

Also: **do NOT** string together your SQL statement like this! This is **highly vulnerable** to SQL injection attacks!

Use a **parametrized query** instead!

```
INSERT INTO [order](user_id, date) VALUES (@UserId, @Date);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

To just insert the row and retrieve the newly inserted `ID`, I'd personally use a simple `SqlCommand` and not go the way of using `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO [order](user_id, date) VALUES (@UserId, @Date); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

using (SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, yourSqlConnection))
{  
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = xy;
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

    yourSqlConnection.Open();
    int newID = (int)insertCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    yourSqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than marc_s answer do not use `dataset` to fetch a single value instead use `ExecuteScalar` method .

```
string sql =
        "INSERT INTO [order] (user_id, date) VALUES (@user_id, @date); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {

       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql , cmd))
         {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                ord_id = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
         }
        }
```

Comment: Great to use `using()` for the `SqlConnection` - and you should also use it for the `SqlCommand` !

Comment: @SurajSingh Use store procedure instead of SQL Query